# Update DateTime to Oracle DB get not a valid month error from c#

Tags: c#, oracle-manageddataaccess

I am making a update to oracle db using `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess`nuget. I can do update non Date data but when I try to insert data it throws `Not a valid month` exception.

```
string cmdQuery = string.Format("UPDATE HKSTF087.FUELCHARGES SET EFFECTIVETHRUDATE = '{0}'  WHERE TITLECODE = '{1}'", currentEffectiveDate.AddSeconds(-1), mtcFuel.TITLECODE);
```

The string looks like

```
"UPDATE HKSTF087.FUELCHARGES SET EFFECTIVETHRUDATE = '8/13/2017 11:59:59 PM'  WHERE TITLECODE = 'SCRUBS'"
```

I tried with other DateTime formats though its not solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Oracle `TO_DATE` function and format your date in the same way.

```
string cmdQuery = string.Format("UPDATE HKSTF087.FUELCHARGES SET EFFECTIVETHRUDATE = TO_DATE('{0:MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss}', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')  WHERE TITLECODE = '{1}'", currentEffectiveDate.AddSeconds(-1), mtcFuel.TITLECODE);
```

But I would recommend that you use parameters for this.